# Why does the iPad render a stretched select element?

Tags: html, ipad, select

On [this site][1] the iPad displays the multi-state select element strangely.  I'm having some trouble finding out why this is - anyone know?  Instead of being rendered as a normal ipad dropdown with a height equal to a single line of text, it has a height of approx. 5-7 lines of text and seems to coorespond with it's size=7' attribute, though I haven't confirmed this yet.

However the ipad displays other multi-select elements with a size greater than 1 correctly.  Why not mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that there was a CSS height specified for that select element in addition to having the "size" attribute set.